# Find the new position of rectangle for resized image

Tags: image, image-processing, matlab

I have a four element position vector `[xmin ymin width hight]` that specifies the size and position of crop rectangle from image I. How can i find the new position and size for the resized image `I`?

Comment: do you have the original image size?

Answer (score 0):

It is not entirely clear, what you want, as we don't know your coordinate system. Assuming x is the horizontal axis and y is the vertical axis and your point (1,1) is at the top left corner, you can use the following snippet:

```
p = [xmin ymin width height];
I = I_orig(p(2):p(2)+p(4)-1,p(1):p(1)+p(3)-1);
```

The size is of course your specified width and height.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your original bounding box to relative values (that is assuming the image size is 1x1)

```
 [origH origW] = size( origI(:,:,1) );
 relativeBB = [xmin / origW, ymin / origH, width / origW, hight / origH];
```

Now, no matter how you resized your `origI`, you can recover the bounding box w.r.t the new size from the relative representation:

```
 [currH currW] = size(I(:,:,1));
 currBB = relativeBB .* [currW, currH, currW, currH];
```

You might need to `round` things a bit: you might find `floor` better for `xmin` and `ymin` and `ceil` more suitable for `width` and `height`.